# "Ineligible" iCloud Songs on iOS devices

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod, icloud, itunes-match

I have some mp3's ripped from a language CD, "Lesson 1", "Lesson 2" and so forth. Some of them are uploaded to iCloud with iTunes Match, for some it says "Ineligible". I don't really need them in the cloud, but on my iOS devices. How do I get them there, as the music sync is disabled when iTunes Match is turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to re-import your audiobooks. Go to each track, right click, get info, options, and select audio book in the field "support type" (I am translating form spanish, I don't know the real name of the field in english).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Works like a charm!

Comment: Works also for the full album, no need to select tracks separately.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, they are ineligbile because the bit rate is less than 96kb so rerip them.  You don't have to do the originals, you can rerip the ones that are already in iTunes.  The audio quality doesn't change and the files are bigger but Match will accept the new ones.

Comment: Indeed it is, didn't know the requirements for iCloud. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can still sync audiobooks.

What you will need to do (as a work around) is import the CD as an audiobook [(instructions here)](http://oakroadsystems.com/genl/itunsabk.htm) then when the device is connected to iTunes you can choose to sync audiobooks.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Too bad the software is all for < 10.7. I'll try to find a compatible app. Thanks!